# Narrow gauge train wheels metal axle?

Tags: trains, tracks

Anyone know some way, (or someone that makes a mod) to make narrow gauge wheels that actually roll fast? Something similar to the metal axle trucks that are used for standard gauge trains.

Comment: Do you mean for lego train wheels that are plastic?